# QGIS Server WMTS custom tile matrix set

Tags: qgis, qgis-server, wmts

I do have a WMTS which implements a special swiss tile matrix set:
https://api3.geo.admin.ch/services/sdiservices.html#wmts

I use the variant 2056_24. I stored a layer from this WMTS in a QGIS project and apply some styling.

Looking at the detail information of the layer in my project I see the following tile matrix definition:
[image]

This corresponds with the Service description linked above.

I then want QGIS Server to serve this layer as WMTS so it acts like a style proxy. I configured the project and set up the matrix set 2056. If I now use this proxied layer I get nicely styled tiles as expected. But in a different tile matrix set:
[image]

It looks like QGIS Server automatically produces something different. The settings of my matrix tile set are:
[image]

Is it possible to define a complete custom tile matrix set to force QGIS Server to imitate the original one?

Comment: Unfortunately your screenshots are too small, the text is unreadable. If possible please include information in text form.

Comment: @bugmenot123 Indeed... Thank you for the hint. I edited my original Post